# Can I increase the 50 save limit?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

Unfortunately, the PC version of Mass Effect 3 has a limit of 50 saves (**[again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52601/can-i-increase-the-number-of-allowed-saves)**). Once more, I've hit the limit. Is there any solution to this for this game?

Yes, moving out saves is possible, as the solution to the linked question for ME2 stated, but it's not ideal. Is there any setting, buried in Coalesced.bin somewhere perhaps, that will allow you to increase the number of allowed saves? Or am I stuck manually moving my saves out again?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can. There is a tool designed for Mass Effect 2 that I tested for Mass Effect 3 - and it works. You can download a zip file of the program [here](http://social.bioware.com/bw_projects_file_download.php?project_file_id=10698).

**Instructions:**

1. Extract the downloaded zip file to `\Program Files\Mass Effect 3\Binaries`.
2. Open the "PCC PATCH" folder and drag the enclosed files directly into the ME3 binaries folder.
3. Open the "PCCPATCHER.EXE" file.
4. File > Open Engine.pcc
   The Engine.pcc file should be located at `\Program Files\Mass Effect 3\BioGame\CookedPCConsole`, unless you changed it.
5. File > Open SFXGame.pcc
   Located here: `\Program Files\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\CookedPCConsole`
6. Select Load Packages on the Main Tab.
7. Select the Gameplay Tab.
8. Check the boxes that you want for your game.
9. Go back to the Main Tab > Save Packages

Hope that helps!

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I attempt to Load Packages, I receive an error that says `Invalid Engine.pcc size`.

Comment: Hmmmm. It worked for me, try updating your game if you haven't already. (I have had the same problem before, this solves it if it's due to an outdated engine) The error message is saying that your engine is the wrong size. Recently I looked on BioWare forums, and other people have encountered the same thing, just update your game(if it is not up to date) and try again. If it is up to date, and you still have problems, than I will contact the creator of this tool and tell them to update it, though I doubt it is a problem with the pccpatcher, because it worked for me with a fully updated ME3.

Comment: Still the same error. :/ For reference, I have the N7 Digital Deluxe version. Origin says it's completely updated as of today.

Comment: Well, I just contacted the creator of pccpatcher, and asked him to update it to fully work with the latest release of ME3. I'll keep ya posted on anything new I receive from him.

Comment: Just thought I'd give an update on this as I would like this addressed as well: I contacted [Epic Legion](http://social.bioware.com/2301325/), the creator of the Mass Effect 2 PCC Patcher project and his reply was, "I'll create ME3 version of my tool soon. I just need to update my dev tools for ME3 demo to work with full version." so it is in the works.